# My Gradle project depends on commons-io 2.4, but Gradle puts $GRADLE_HOME/commons-io-1.4.jar into the classpath, causing failures

Tags: groovy, gradle, apache-commons-io

I've been iterating on features in my first Gradle plugin.  I determined early on that I needed commons-io, so I added a dependency on commons-io 2.4, being the latest version.

This has been going well for a while, with the build working from the command line, and no errors in Eclipse.

I just started trying to integrate some code that uses "FileUtils.write(File,String)".  I didn't need that method before.  I got everything un-redded in Eclipse, and then I tried a command line build.

This failed with errors like the following:

```
    ... error: cannot find symbol
                FileUtils.write(serviceLoaderFile,
                         ^
  symbol:   method write(File,String)
  location: class FileUtils
```

This confused me.  I went to the failing lines in Eclipse, and no issues were indicated.  I navigated into the "write()" method, and it looked fine to me.  I then ran my command-line build with "--debug" to get some clues.

When I found the "javac" line, I found that "$GRADLE_HOME\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar" (where "GRADLE_HOME" is just my Gradle 2.3 distribution) was in the classpath BEFORE my dependency jar. I then inspected the code in the 1.4 jar, and I determined that the "FileUtils" class in that version didn't have a "write" method.

What am I supposed to do about this?

**Update**:

I suppose it's likely my "dependencies" block would be useful, which is this:

```
dependencies {
  compile ("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9")
  compile gradleApi()
  compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-java-api-generator:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-generator-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-generator-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "org.opendaylight.controller:yang-jmx-generator:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

  testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3") {
    exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
  }
```

I tried commenting out the "gradleApi" reference, and that had no effect.  I also tried adding an "exclude" for commons-io associated with the "groovy-all" reference, but that also didn't appear to make any difference.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this required adding the following block to the "sourceSets" block:

```
main {
    compileClasspath = configurations.compile.minus files("$gradle.gradleHomeDir/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar")
}
```

This is pretty simple, but I wish there was a cleaner solution for this.  I'm not sure what that would look like.

Answer (score 1):

You probably added `gradleApi()` under `dependencies {}` block - see the [docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#gradleApi()). The problem is that it ships all dependencies gradle requires - including `commons-io` in version *1.4* - see the extract below:

```
[opal@opal-mac-2]~/.gvm/gradle/current/lib % pwd
/Users/opal/.gvm/gradle/current/lib
[opal@opal-mac-2]~/.gvm/gradle/current/lib % ll commons-io-1.4.jar 
-rw-rw-r--  1 opal  staff  109043 23 gru 13:17 commons-io-1.4.jar
[opal@opal-mac-2]~/.gvm/gradle/current/lib %
```

You probably added version *2.4* separately and that's why conflict occurred. You can also run

```
gradle dependencies
```

to view the full dependency tree and verify the problem.

There's no possibility to exclude a transitive dependency from `gradleApi()`.

Comment: As I noted in the update I made concurrent with your answer, I thought that might be the issue, but when I commented it out, it made no difference.

Comment: And just in case, I tried doing "gradle dependencies" to see if there were any other unexpected references to commons-io 1.4, and there were not, only my one reference to 2.4.

Comment: It may be cached - try to remove `.gradle` folder. You will probably not provide a plugin without `gradleApi()`. See updated answer.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr - sounds really strange. It must be cached somewhere. Does it fail with command line and eclipse?

Comment: It's only failing on the command line.  Eclipse shows no red marks.

Comment: Ok, and you have now both versions of commons-io in classpath?

Comment: Correct, and note that the reference to 1.4 in the classpath is not out of my cache, it's out of the Gradle distribution directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74214/discussion-between-opal-and-david-m-karr).