# Android gradle JAR dependency ends up declared as native

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android projects `build.gradle` file I have:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
}
```

When I run `aapt dump badging` I see:

```
native-code: 'commons-io-2.4.jar'
```

Clearly commons-io is not native code but the Android Gradle plugin thinks it is. How can I tell the Android Gradle plugin this library does not contain native code? Also curious how did it decide what architecture this library is? It seems to have picked some variety of `arm` since the APK won't install on a intel-based Android emulator, it gives the error: `INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE`.

Comment: possible answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20185696/794088

Comment: I saw that question but it is all about IntelliJ, I tried using IntelliJ but I get a bunch of errors in IntelliJ. I only really care about the configuration for command line builds with gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using the incorrect Commons IO library. Try:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4

The [version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.io/2.4) you're using seems to be specific to [Apache Directory Studio 2.4](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) which seems to be a desktop app.

Comment: Using `commons-io:commons-io:2.4` fixed it. If you look inside the one I was using before it was a JAR with a `lib` directory in it that contained another JAR. My guess is that it was the presences of that `lib` directory that made the android gradle plugin think it was native. I'm surprised that weird JAR worked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I once had troubles introducing a dependency on `commons-io:2.4` into my build code. The problem is that Gradle itself comes with a version of `commons-io`. In my case it could be fixed with this:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    compileClasspath = configurations.compile.minus files("$gradle.gradleHomeDir/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar")
  }
}
```

I took this snippet from [My Gradle project depends on commons-io 2.4, but Gradle puts $GRADLE_HOME/commons-io-1.4.jar into the classpath, causing failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377544/my-gradle-project-depends-on-commons-io-2-4-but-gradle-puts-gradle-home-common)

But be aware that it is not recommended to use different versions of libraries to come with Gradle.

You can find more information about this here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unable-to-use-commons-io-2-4-because-gradle-forces-the-loading-of-commons-io-1-4/8021

This might aswell be completely unrelated :)